# SQL How to convert a date into hours per minute? Then subtract two of the colums (end-start) and set it as a new column?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am wondering, how can I convert datetime into hours per minute? I want the following. To minus the end_trip with the start_trip that is in hours and minutes. Moreover, I want to create a new column for the result. However, I am getting nowhere. I want to use basic arithmetic for this not some built in functions like DATEDIFF. Please help.

Below is my code

```
INSERT INTO TRIP VALUES( 
TO_DATE('26-01-2022 14:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), - start_time 
TO_DATE('26-01-2022 14:50:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')  - end_time
; 

SELECT 
trip_start_actual as start_time, trip_end_actual as end_time, (trip_end_actual - trip_start_actual)
from trip;
commit;
```

Answer (score 1):

Subtracting two dates in Oracle will yield a difference in fractional days.  To get minutes from that, simply multiply that difference by 1440:

```sql
SELECT trip_start_actual AS start_time,
       trip_end_actual AS end_time,
       1440 * (trip_end_actual - trip_start_actual) AS num_minutes
FROM trip;
```

Comment: Hi, I forgot to ask how do I round it to the nearest whole minutes?

Comment: @KellyLee Wrap the `num_minutes` expression in `ROUND(...)` to round to the nearest integer.

Answer (score 1):

when we subtract two dates in oracle the difference integer also comes in days. we need to multiply that by 24 to get hours and multiply by 24 * 60 = 1440 to get minutes and multiply by 24 * 60 * 60 = 86400 to get seconds.

```
SELECT 
trip_start_actual as start_time, trip_end_actual as end_time, 
round ((trip_end_actual - trip_start_actual) * 24 * 60) as 
time_diff_minutes from trip;
```